# ActiveRecord Import - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree, solidus, activerecord-import

Attempting to update a large dataset with ActiveRecord Import, I'm struggling to see why my insert is failing.

In my schema for the model, this line exists:

`t.index ["variant_id", "stock_location_id"], name: "index_spree_stock_items_on_variant_id_and_stock_location_id", unique: true, where: "(deleted_at IS NULL)"`

For the import, I'm trying to update many of these, when I run:

`Spree::StockItem.import columns, values, :on_duplicate_key_update => [:count_on_hand]`

I receive:

`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_spree_stock_items_on_variant_id_and_stock_location_id"`

but when I run:

`Spree::StockItem.import columns, values, :on_duplicate_key_update =>{ conflict_target: [:index_spree_stock_items_on_variant_id_and_stock_location_id], columns: [:count_on_hand] }`

I receive:

`column "index_spree_stock_items_on_variant_id_and_stock_location_id" does not exist`

Why does it say this column doesn't exist? Are indexes not considered columns available for duplicate key checks? How should I check for duplicate via an index which is a combination of two columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use column names instead of index name for `conflict_target` like this

```
Spree::StockItem.import(
  columns,
  values,
  on_duplicate_key_update: {
    conflict_target [:variant_id, :stock_location_id],
    columns: [:count_on_hand]
  }
)
```